# Powerpivot diagram view keeps showing blank screen?

Tags: excel, diagram, powerpivot, visual-glitch

> *I wasn't exactly sure, whether to post this on [superuser](https://superuser.com), given this is likely a visual bug,
>   but who knows, maybe I'm just doing something incorrectly given I'm
>   new to [powerpivot](/questions/tagged/powerpivot)*

- I've recently imported rather large sets of data into my Excel.
- The import seemed to have went down fine, as data shows correctly inside my PowerPivot

Issue is, when I switch to the Diagram view, for some reason my [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) keeps on showing blank screen, rather than the two tables in Diagram view.

[image]

Any idea what could be the cause behind the issue / how to fix it?

*(Yes, I did try turning Excel off and on)*

Comment: Try turning the power pivot add in off and on.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz check ther last line of my question. Already tried

Comment: You said Excel, not the add-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer and I don't understand how/why it works, but at least it fixed the issue for me:

- Open the same file on a different computer *(eg. I used my laptop)*
- The diagram view should work now, save a separate copy of the file and upload it to your computer *(where it doesn't work)*
- The diagram view should work now.

Not really sure what caused this bug, or even why it fixed it, but it seemed to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:
1) Make sure "Show Hidden" is toggled in case the table you brought in accidentally got hidden some how. 
2) It is possible that the table is there but you are zoomed in and the table is on a different part of the screen.There is a "Fit to Screen" button at the bottom right hand. Click this so you can see if the table is elsewhere off screen.

Thanks,

Brett

[Fit to Screen Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3ima.png)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I tried both toggling the 'Hidden items' and also clicking 'Fit to screen' in both cases. Unfortunately to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually creating a relationship between the two tables? I'm assuming that's what you're trying to do in Diagram View.

In Power Pivot, on the 'Design' tab, click 'Create Relationship'.  Select each table and the related column.  If you get a one-to-many error, flip the order of the tables.

If your two tables don't directly join, continue adding in your data and then create the relationships.  Then check the Diagram View and see if it cooperated.

Other ideas - try creating a dummy table in your Excel sheet, convert to a table, then use the 'Add to Data Model' command.  Your dummy table will show up in Power Pivot and maybe it will nudge PP into normal behavior.